# GPS showing double the speed? System setting?

Tags: gps

I use a "Enco B039" android-run in-dash car stereo. When using the gps the speed I drive in is showing double the speed. So if I'm going 50km/h the gps software tells me I'm going 100km/h and so on. All the settings in the software are set to km/h so I suspect it's the android system that communicates with the gps-module fault? I read in another forum of a guy that discovered that his android phone was giving him the speed reading in nautical miles (nots). Maybe this is whats happening with my unit? I found the system file "gps.conf" but I can't see any settings in there that I can change when it comes to speed. Any suggestions? In what file in the system is this setting located? Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried with different apps first? Concluding a system fault from just a single app's output would be a bit brave ;)

Comment: I have used IGo, TomTom, Sygic, Navigon. All the same. It shows the speed in nautical miles. It's a bug in these units and I haven't figured it out yet.